# jQuery UI : How to make parent to follow the child element on drag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am making an `<div>` element and it has some child elements and also textnodes. I binded draggable function to one of the child element of `<div>` element. I thought of using draggable `drag` event i can achieve what i want but it becomes wierd with that.

[***Fiddle Link***](http://jsfiddle.net/y6XDr/)

HTML:

```
<div class="parent" style="margin:50px; width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;position:relative;">
    <div class="child" style="border-radius:4px 4px 4px; background:#000;position:absolute;top:-5px;left:-5px;width:10px;height:10px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".child").draggable({
  drag:function() {
    $(this).parent().css({ "top":$(this).offset().top+"px", "left": $(this).offset().left+"px" });
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.child:hover {
  cursor:crosshair;
}
```

But It is a wierd way. I know the logic is not good but still i thought it will work.

Comment: If you want the parent to be draggable, then invoke `.draggable()` on the parent. AFAIK, child elements can be independently draggable in addition to their parent, if that's what you want.

Comment: you haven't explained what expected behavior is

Comment: @charlietfl when that black circle is dragged i want that box also to be moved with the black circle div! Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: did you try setting `margin` instead of `top`? Concept hard to follow if div has multiple children and that all change parent position